# Clirr And Default Methods

Tags: maven

I'm trying to use [Clirr](http://www.mojohaus.org/clirr-maven-plugin/) like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>clirr-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

However it fails if I add a default method to an interface, even though that shouldn't be an API break.

There is a [closed issue](https://github.com/mojohaus/clirr-maven-plugin/issues/3) for Java 8 support, but the last comment is: *Note that even though this issue is closed, it doesn't add support for Java 8 as the issue title claims ;) It just makes it not fail if you're under java 8 but use java 7 constructs.*

So does Clirr support Java 8? If so, how do I enable it?

Comment: The underlaying Clirr is from 2006 ...I have my doubts that there will be any new release which might support java 8...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve using Clirr? When do you get the error please elaborate? Though agreed the contributions seems to be dying to the plugin.

Comment: @khmarbaise The Clirr homepage states "Last published: 2016-09-13" and the bug I linked is from 2015, so I kind of hoped it was still maintained.

Comment: @nullpointer What info is missing? I try to check my API stability, which seems to work except for default methods. And I just want to make sure I'm not just using the plug-in wrong.

Comment: @SteffiS. You are talking about the homepage of the clirr-maven-plugin and not of the underlaying Clirr itself...

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes, of course. And you're right. I figured you wouldn't need to update the homepage if nothing was changed in the plug-in itself. But I was deceived by the Clirr masterminds ;)